# Looping an Array and storing values in a table

Tags: php, arrays, loops, datatables, nested

Good afternoon good people.

(please be nice I'm new to PHP Arrays and Loops are not the strongest)

I've been working on a **nested loop** and I'm struggling to understand why I am unable to print the value into a table.

When I try the following code I get Array to string conversion. I understand that the computer thinks I'm trying to **print an array to the DOM** which is a no-go but I've made a for loop that should be turning the array values to string so that they can be iterated over and then printed to the dom.

Here is the code

```
$parts = ["tires", "wheels", "Exhaust", "windows", "suspension", "The Wheel", "Clutch", "Gears", 
"Radio", "Bonnit"];
$upholstery = ["plastic", "polished wood", "fabric", "silk", "cotton", "rubber", "metal", "Arcylic", 
"Leather", "Faux Leather"];


for($i=0; $i<=9; $i++)
{
$Arr_Data['Vehicle']['parts'] = $parts;

for($j=0; $j<=9; $j++)
{
   
    $Arr_Data['Vehicle']['upholstery'] = $upholstery;
}

}



foreach($Arr_Data as $key=> $value)
{

 $HTML_tableheadings = '<th>'. $value['parts'] .'</th>';

};

$Table = 
'<table> 
    <tr>'.$HTML_tableheadings.'</tr>
</table>';


echo $Table;
```

Comment: There are multiple issues with your code. The first one (the one causing the error) being that you're storing the entire array in each iteration of your `for` loops (you need `$parts[$i]` and `$upholstery[$j]` to access the element at the current index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print all `keys->value` from array you need to define a variable for HTML output first, after you need to use ".=" to expand the variable:

```
$HTML_tableheadings = '';
foreach($Arr_Data['Vehicle']['parts'] as $parts) {
    $HTML_tableheadings .= '<th>'. $parts .'</th>';
};
```

In $Table variable you don't need to write the `<tr></tr>` tags, because is not valid table format:

```
$Table = 
'<table> 
    '.$HTML_tableheadings.'
</table>';
```

The last step, then you need to define exactly what you want from array. Your array look like this:

```
Array
(
    [Vehicle] => Array
        (
            [parts] => Array
                (
                    [0] => tires
                    [1] => wheels
                    [2] => Exhaust
                    [3] => windows
                    [4] => suspension
                    [5] => The Wheel
                    [6] => Clutch
                    [7] => Gears
                    [8] => Radio
                    [9] => Bonnit
                )

            [upholstery] => Array
                (
                    [0] => plastic
                    [1] => polished wood
                    [2] => fabric
                    [3] => silk
                    [4] => cotton
                    [5] => rubber
                    [6] => metal
                    [7] => Arcylic
                    [8] => Leather
                    [9] => Faux Leather
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: many thanks @Gabor, I knew I wasn't too far off. This has helped hugely

Comment: @JDDev You welcome. Please accept my answer